# Madden 16 problem on XB1 - resetting every time

Tags: xbox-one, madden-16

Every single time I put Madden 16 in my Xbox One it makes me replay the "Super Bowl 50" intro and then pick a favorite team (as if I've never played the game before). This intro takes around 11 minutes. It's an insanely annoying problem. Basically catastrophic as far as game glitches can be.  Anyone know of this or have any ideas on how to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem on last years release too.

It turns out that EA Support still haven't fixed the bug in the latest release **[based on this](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Madden-16-keeps-playing-intro/td-p/4751288)**.

The way I got around it before was by deleting my local files (profile, saves etc).  This shouldn't affect online game modes like Ultimate Team, but you may lose local/single player progress.

Anyway, once you have done that, you will go through the intro one last time (hopefully).  I'm guessing there is some corruption in the profile files that is causing the game to think you haven't played the game before, and after the intro the file is not updated correctly.